# Spaces between divs: how do I stop this?

Tags: css

I have a problem where if I write divs like this:

```
 <div class="asdf">
      Some content..
 </div>
 <div class="asdf2">
       Some content
 </div>
```

Then the two divs render with a space in between. If I write it has such:

```
 <div class="asdf">
      Some content..
 </div> <div class="asdf2">
       Some content
 </div>
```

Then a space appears between the divs... BUT i I write it as such:

```
 <div class="asdf">
      Some content..
 </div><div class="asdf2">
       Some content
 </div>
```

Then no space appears between the divs. How is it that this is the case? How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a little unclear. Do you mean a blank line in between the two divs? And for the second part, if you "write it as such", what happens?

Comment: Do you see any rails code here? Your css is doing that.

Comment: fixed problems and added clarifications.. didn't realize how much i left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, HTML renders white space. I assume that you're rendering these div's inline? The solution you gave is, simply put, the solution.